# Ignore script error and carry on loading page

Tags: javascript

I have a module in NodeJS (SocketIO), and clients load it via:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?PHP echo $socketServer; ?>socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.15:8123');
    </script>
```

The problem is, is if the Node server is offline the script will break and the rest of the page will stop loading.

My app does not depend on Node to function properly, so I need everything to carry on loading whether or not Node is working.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

If socket.io script is optional, then you can implement lazy loading of script:

```
function lazyLoad(url, callback) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;

  script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (script.loaded == false && (!this.readyState || this.readyState == 'complete')) {
      script.loaded = true;

      console.log('script loaded');
      callback();
    }
  };
  script.onerror = function() {
    console.log('error loading');
  }

  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Then use it that way:

```
lazyLoad('/socket.io/socket.io.js', function() {
  try {
    var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.15:8123');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

BTW, make sure you load and connect to socket.io on the same server, otherwise you will face issues with CORS and many security limitations based on different browsers security policies.

Comment: @MaksimsMihjevs If I try this I get "Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null :/

Comment: Is that happens on line: `document.body.appendChild(script);`? Make sure you call `lazyLoad` after page is loaded `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care at all about result of `io.connect` just place into try/catch statement and ignore the exception

```
<script type="text/javascript">
try {
      var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.15:8123');
} catch (e) {
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is a bit rude way of checking. As well taking in account that `socket.io.js` will be loaded from same server, then usually both will be unavailable. And when browser will try to load unavailable script, if its in head - it will dramatically delay page load, so lazy load or async parameter is required to prevent idling page load till timeout triggers.
And you just copy pasted my code from below, and messed up indention..

Comment: I bow to master :) And oh yeah I always copypaste when I am to lazy to load (no pun intended) bunch of text manually